# AppTransaction issues for previous purchases under VPP

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, storekit, receipt-validation, storekit2

I recently migrated my app to freemium model from paid and am using `AppTransaction` in StoreKit 2 to get original purchase version and original purchase date to determine if user already paid for the app before or not. It seems to be working for normal AppStore users but I am now flooded with complains from VPP users who previously purchased the app. It seems AppTransaction history is absent for these users and these users are asked to sign-in using Apple ID.

What is the solution here?